# Looping a code through a folder of workbooks with VBA?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a folder with a number of excel files all with the same format. I have modified the following code to determine the date and reformat it, where "i" determines the number of cells in the range based on the last row of column 2.

```
Sub Test()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   With Range("K3:K" & i)
        .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
        .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
   End With  
End Sub
```

I would like to perform this code on all the workbooks in my folder. I have found the following question on stackoverflow:

[Code for looping through all excel files in a specified folder, and pulling data from specific cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851531/code-for-looping-through-all-excel-files-in-a-specified-folder-and-pulling-data)

It does not loop through all my files, and only works on the first excel file I have opened.
How can I loop this code through all workbooks in a folder? Below is what I have so far.

```
Sub Test()
Dim lCount As Long
Dim wbResults As Workbook
Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
    Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook
        With Application.FileSearch
            .NewSearch

            .LookIn = "C:\Test"
            .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks

                If .Execute > 0 Then
                    For lCount = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count

                        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(lCount), UpdateLinks:=0)

   i = wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   With wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & i)
        .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
        .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
   End With

                        wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    Next lCount
                End If
        End With
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: from your link you have this line: `Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(...`. Next your step would be `i = wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` and `With wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & i)`

Comment: I have attemped the change, but it did make any changes to my workbooks. The workbooks had their file name as the sheet name, I changed 3 of them to sheet1 to see if that was the problem, but it still does not work. I have attached the code I entered into the main question.

Comment: maybe it's because `wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False` - you close workbooks without saving changes:)

Comment: That would make sense. It doesn't seem to be running the code at all though. I have one of the workbooks open and when I run no changes happen. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: try to remove `On Error Resume Next` statement. Would you get some errors?

Comment: Yes, it says run-time error 445 and highlights the line "With Application.FileSearch"

Comment: Application.FileSearch has been deprecated from Excel 2007 onward. Try to implement code from this link: http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/

Comment: I am new to vba, so I can't say I understand what I need to do with that link. I have found another question that may help my purpose:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/macro-loop-through-all-subfolders/605972b8-f8f1-4719-9e02-fd79b32ea68e?auth=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.FileSearch` doesn't supported by Excel 2007 and later. Try this code ([**code for looping through files in a folder was taken from @mehow's site**](http://vba4all.com/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/))

```
Sub PrintFilesNames()
    Dim file As String
    Dim wbResults As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    myPath = "D:\" ' note, path ends with back slash

    file = Dir$(myPath & "*.xls*")

    While (Len(file) > 0)
        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & file, UpdateLinks:=0)

        With wbResults.Worksheets(Split(file, ".")(0))
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Range("K3:K" & i)
                 .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
                 .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
            End With
        End With

        wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'get next file
        file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error at the line: 
With wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1"). The error says wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1") = <automation error>

I also want to note I'm working with csv files, I changed xls to csv in the code, would that effect it?

Comment: ahh I did not know that, that is a whole other problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: actually it would store *result* of formulas after saving. And btw, I've just tested it with csv file - it works for me without any errors.

Comment: Hmm yes, I converted my files to xls and I still get the an error on With wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet1"), where it says = <Subscript out of range>

Comment: have you done some changes in my code? `Subscript out of range` means that workbook doesn't contains sheet with name `Sheet1`

Comment: Ahh I see, the sheet name on my excel files have reverted back to their original name "same name as the file". I changed them earlier in csv, but it did not save. That is most likely the issue.

Comment: in that case try to use this one: `With wbResults.Worksheets(Split(file, ".")(0))` - it cut's extension (.csv or .xls) from filename and use it as sheet name

Comment: Excellent! your expertise is very much appreciated, Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by Chris Newman's post on *The Spreadsheet Guru*
Copy and paste this entire code block, replacing the one line "wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)" with your specific code to be performed on each workbook.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

'----------------------------------------------------------
'----------------------------------------------------------
'Here is where action code goes, what is going to be performed on each workbook
    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
'----------------------------------------------------------
'----------------------------------------------------------

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```