# Macros to split large data to separate workbooks and worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I'm looking to combine 2 macros to split large data in Excel to many workbooks and each workbook should be split to separate worksheets. Column A should determine the split in to workbooks and Column B should split to separate worksheets within each new workbook. Here are the 2 macros:

**1)**

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**2)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 3
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Test\"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have told us what the task you want to accomplish is, now what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I would like to run 1 macro so that if it's already split in separate workbooks, I don't need to run the macro in each workbook.

Comment: That is your goal, not the problem. What have you tried? Can you show us your attempt at combining the two macros and explain how it fails to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new at VBA. That's my problem - I don't know how to combine the 2 macros in 1 run. Once I create separate workbooks, I need to run the splitworksheet macro in each workbook. I have 100 workbooks after splitting.

Comment: [This may help get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851531/code-for-looping-through-all-excel-files-in-a-specified-folder-and-pulling-data)

Comment: I am willing to try if no one answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the program to run the first "Sub parse_data()" after or coworking with "ExportToWorkbooks" (the second one), then you can change the field **ws** in the first one to an argument and call it on each Workbook having been added.

Just Only the two lines are necessary:

```
Sub parse_data(ws As Worksheet)
```

```
Call parse_data (dws)
```

And comment out the line:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Because you've set it to the currently processed sheet when call the *parse_data()* procedure.

so your code will be:

```vb
Sub parse_data(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim lr As Long
'    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
'    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 3
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Test\"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        

        'save file Just in case
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Call parse_data (dws)

        
        'save it again prepaer to close
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! But it doesn't seem to run/start at all.

Comment: @Sarah you can give me a sample and I WILL try to show you as a demo.

Comment: Thanks Oscar! It finally started running, but it only created separate workbooks not worksheets.

Comment: In Excel columns, it's listed like this: Caregiver Code Name Year Week Start Date End Date Sum of Live In Visit
13363 Employee1 2016 Week 1 12/27/2015 1/2/2016 2
13364 Employee2 2017 Week 2 1/3/2016 1/9/2016 3
13365 Employee3 2018 Week 3 1/10/2016 1/16/2016 3
13366 Employee4 2019 Week 4 1/17/2016 1/23/2016 3
13367 Employee5 2020 Week 5 1/24/2016 1/30/2016 3
13368 Employee6 2021 Week 6 1/31/2016 2/6/2016 3
13369 Employee7 2022 Week 7 2/7/2016 2/13/2016 3
13370 Employee8 2023 Week 8 2/14/2016 2/20/2016 3

Comment: I finally got it to work! But it created the workbooks but only filtered for the column and then created the worksheet for only 1 value instead of filtering the next value and creating another worksheet.

Comment: @Sarah I'm just trying to connect them together in a logical way as an automated operation. If it is something that your original code cannot do, of course, I have no idea. Without actual samples, I can't test the results at all. I believe you can understand. So please think about the model I propose and figure out for yourself how it could be implemented and where it could go wrong.